# ¿Cómo llenar dropdownlist desde c# y mostrarlo en modal bootstrap?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto en [ASP.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet) en el cual tengo `Gridview` el cual tiene un `ButtonLink`, que al dar click abre una ventana modal con un `DropdownList` dentro, ahora el `DropdownList` se debe llenar con una consulta a la base de datos usando un código del datakeynames de mi primer `Gridview`. El problema es que el `dropdownlist` no muestra los datos, pero al depurar el código no muestra error alguno, y supuestamente si lo está llenando bien.

```html
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
codigo = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();
if (e.CommandName == "Datos")
{
LlenarDrop();
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ModalView", "<script>$(function() { $('#ModalSem').modal('show'); });</script>", false);
}
}

private void LlenarDrop()
{
  try
  {
  string query = "select Campo, Descripcion from MyTabla where Codigo='" + codigo + "'";
  SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds, "MyTabla");
  DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTabla"];
  DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Campo";
  DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Descripcion";
  DropDownList2.DataBind();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; width: auto; padding: 0 0 0 2%">
<h6>Elegir dato</h6>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">-Seleccione una opcion-</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto, y revisa este [link](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/6902453)

```html
<div class="modal  fade" id="ModalSem" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="modal-content">
...
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</div>
```

```html
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
codigo = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();
if (e.CommandName == "Datos")
{
LlenarDrop();
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ModalView", "<script>$(function() { $('#ModalSem').modal('show'); });</script>", false);
upModal.Update();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me paso lo mismo agregue el combo dentro de un update panel y 4 
 debajo del combo y funciono bien

[image: combobox]

[image: codigo]

[image: 4 enter debajo del combo]

Answer (score 0):

Modifica el **DataSet** por **DataTable**.

```
try
{
    string query = "select Campo, Descripcion from MyTabla where Codigo='" + codigo + "'";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Campo";
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Descripcion";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    ex.ToString(); 
}
```

Para el uso del **DataTable**, agrega la librería que corresponda.

Me comentas

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero es el mismo caso, no me muestra los datos, sucede que tengo otro dropdownlist y lo lleno de la misma manera y si funciona, creo que el problema es porque esta dentro de una ventana modal de bootstrap, pero no entiendo porque pasa esto

Comment: Pon **try-catch** en el evento: **GridView1_RowCommand**, quizá ni siquiera entra ahí. Pon puntos de interrupción para validar que tus variables **index** y **codigo** tengan data.

Comment: Creo que el problema es más basado en que cuando se carga la forma el dropdown no tiene datos, hasta que se hace click en el elemento del GridView y se muestra el modal, creo que ocuparas implementar un update_panel para recibir el evento del gridview y actualizar la vista.